# For update of this query expression is not allowed (Cursor)

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I am running below query

```
Select location, sum(units) as Units
from
( Select a.from_loc as location, sum(units) as units
from emp a, dept b
where a.id=b.id
Union all
Select a.to_loc as location, sum(units) as units
feom emp a, dept b
where a.id=b.id)
group by location;
```

Above query is giving me data in below format.

```
Location | sum(Units)
--------------------
100      |  350
200      |  450
```

Now i need to update another table Class with units given by above query.
Class is having Location as primary key column and units column also.

I tried to create a cursor but its throwing error, for update cannot be used

Here is snippet of cursor code

```
Declare
V_location number(20);
V_units (20),
Cursor c1 is
Select location, sum(units) as Units
from
 ( Select a.from_loc as location, sum(units) as units
   from emp a, dept b
    where a.id=b.id
    Union all
    Select a.to_loc as location, sum(units) as units
     from emp a, dept b
     where a.id=b.id)
      group by location -----above select query
 for update;
Begin
 Open c1;
 Loop
 Fetch c1 into v_location, v_units;
 Exit when c1%notfound;

 Update class set units=v_units
 where location=v_location;
  End loop;
  Close c1;
 End;
```

Its throwing For update of this query expression is not allowed
Could someone please let me know what i am doing wrong in here. Or some other approach to update the class table

Comment: which what ora-error you are getting. what is your `V_units (20)` - you did not mentioned the data type

Comment: @AtulKrDey thank you atul. I am getting ora-01786 error
And i have mentioned datatype for v_units as number(20). This was a typo

Comment: @user8855619 remove `for update;` from your query and then run the block. No need for row locking using `for update` in cursor. Data would anyways flow in sequence in your cursor.

Comment: @XING thank you. I thought for update is mandatory if i have to perform update operation

Comment: @user8855619 No..its not mandatory. Your code will work fine if your remove `for update`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this do any good?

- I presume that the `FOR UPDATE` clause causes problems
- I removed the whole `DECLARE` section and used your `SELECT` statement in a cursor `FOR` loop as it is easier to maintain (no opening, closing, exiting, ...)

---

```
BEGIN
   FOR cur_r IN (  SELECT location, SUM (units) AS units
                     FROM (SELECT a.from_loc AS location, SUM (units) AS units
                             FROM emp a, dept b
                            WHERE a.id = b.id
                           UNION ALL
                           SELECT a.to_loc AS location, SUM (units) AS units
                             FROM emp a, dept b
                            WHERE a.id = b.id)
                 GROUP BY location)
   LOOP
      UPDATE class
         SET units = cur_r.units
       WHERE location = cur_r.location;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

**[EDIT, after reading a comment]**

`IF-THEN-ELSE` is to be done using `CASE` (or `DECODE`); for example:

```
update class set
  units = case when location between 1 and 100 then cur_r.units / 10
               else cur_r.units / 20
          end
where location = cur_r.location
```

Comment: Thank you littlefoot. It worked fine. I have one more question. 
While updating units column in class table inside the loop, can i set the default value to 0 if location is not present in cur_r.location

I tried using case

    Update class
    Set units=case
    When (location=cur_r.location)
    Then cur_r.units
    Else 0
    End

Comment: You're welcome. As of your question: cursor query will return certain locations. UPDATE will update the UNITS column for locations returned by cursor. Therefore, you can't do what you described. If UNITS has to have a default value of 0, consider altering that column, i.e. `alter table class modify units default 0;`

Comment: Thank you. I have one more question. Why this cursor doesn't need to be closed. Or to be on safer side we can close it. Is there any documentation where i can read different types of cursors..

Comment: Oracle closes it for you. If you declare it, open, fetch, take care about exiting the loop and closing the cursor - no problem, it'll work just fine. But, a cursor FOR loop is (as you can see) much easier to maintain. Let Oracle do the dirty job. As of "cursors" themselves, they are described in documentation which is available on Oracle Technology Network. Pick the version you use and read it (although, nothing *much* changed for cursors, so any version would be more or less OK).

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi littlefoot. Sorry for troubling you again. 
In the above loop, how can i use if else statement. 
I mean i want to update class and set units =cur_r.units/10 where location =cur_r.location (here if my location falls between 1 to 100, units =cur_r.units/10
else units=cur_units/20)

Or it needs to be done via some other way